# What is the correct term for a file something.zip? ".zip" or "zip"?

Tags: documentation, file-type

I am looking for the correct term to use when writing about a .zip file (presumably the answer will be the same for other file types as well). I am working on the documentation for a project, and both ".zip" and "zip" is used by other authors before. Sources on the internet seem to be inconsistent and I can't find any straight forward answer on the matter. Any real sources on which one is the correct term is very welcome.

The most trusted source I find is the Python documentation, which seems to consistently use "zip". [Link.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html)

Meanwhile, the Wikipedia page seems to mix "zip" and ".zip". [Link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about human language. [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**zip** is accepted as the name of the lossless compression format developed in the late 1980s by Phil Katz.

`.zip` denotes a file extension that is *probably* associated with that format. Not all **zip** formats have the `.zip` extension; notable examples are the `.jar` files of Java, and the newer Excel formats `.xlsx` and `.xlsm`.

If I were you, I'd adopt the former (i.e. **zip**), and amend Wikipedia if you get the chance.

(Cf. **tarball** and `.tar`).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you'll find a written rule about this (I'm sure you've done some Google'ing already and came up empty), but I can give you the advice I give my coders and analysts that I work with:  Be Consistent.  If you choose one way, stick to it otherwise you'll have people assuming you're switching for a reason.

Wiki is collaboratively edited, thus you'll almost always have inconsistencies; Python Docs are more stringently edited and proofread.

Personally, I always put the "." before referencing any file type I believe my audience may not be intimately familiar with to alert them that it is a file extension.  In analytics, I can get away with CSV, TXT, and XLSX, but I add it for .ZIP, .GZ, etc.